# How to write this: “------------------\r\n“

Tags: symbols, characters

When I try to write the above expression I get an error stating: "Undefined control sequence".

The same when I try to write this: ‘\r\n’.

Any ideas?

Comment: You should add more proper data to what you have done so far..

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.  For future questions, it might help to explain a bit what you're doing and why.  For example, I agree with Fran that it looks like you're trying to typeset code of some sort, in which case there are a few package that make that go much easier.

Answer (score 7):

Any character sequence (word or single character) preceded by a backslash (`\<whatever>`) is a command (=control sequence) in LaTeX, but whereas `\r` is defined (to type characters as `\r{a}`), `\n` has not a predefined function (is "undefined"), so your alternatives to remove the error are
type it verbatim (`\verb|\n|`)  or as plain text (`\textbackslash n`), or
defining it to make something, i.e., make a LaTeX macro:

```
\newcommand\n{\textbackslash n}
\n
```

If what you show is part of a code listing, then  you should consider use a verbatim environment:

```
\begin{verbatim}
----------\n\t  
\end{verbatim}
```

Or use some package for [powered verbatim typesetting](https://www.ctan.org/topic/verbatim) or [syntax highlight](https://www.ctan.org/topic/synt-hlt).